# Userform: Keep Running Total in Textbox

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I want a textbox value to update every time the list boxes are updated in my userform. I have two userforms that the user can move values back and forth between). I would like the textbox value to be updated each time values move back and forth between the userforms. Here is the code I have below.

```
Private Sub btnMoveLeft_Click()

Dim iCtr As Long

For iCtr = 0 To Me.lstAssigned.ListCount - 1
    If Me.lstAssigned.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
        Me.lstUnassigned.AddItem Me.lstAssigned.List(iCtr)
        lookValue = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.lstUnassigned(iCtr), Sheets("Pivot").Range("A:J"), 10, False)
        txtAC.Value = txtAC.Value - lookValue
    End If
Next iCtr

For iCtr = Me.lstAssigned.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If Me.lstAssigned.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
        Me.lstAssigned.RemoveItem iCtr
    End If
Next iCtr

End Sub

Private Sub btnMoveRight_Click()

Dim iCtr As Long

For iCtr = 0 To Me.lstUnassigned.ListCount - 1
    If Me.lstUnassigned.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
        Me.lstAssigned.AddItem Me.lstUnassigned.List(iCtr)
        lookValue = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.lstAssigned.List(iCtr), Sheets("Pivot").Range("A:J"), 10, False)
        txtAC.Value = txtAC.Value + lookValue
    End If
Next iCtr

For iCtr = Me.lstUnassigned.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If Me.lstUnassigned.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
        Me.lstUnassigned.RemoveItem iCtr
    End If
Next iCtr

End Sub
```

The error I currently receive is when it is trying to grab lookValue, the error says "Could not get the List property. Invalid property array index." Any help would be appreciated thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In so many cases, you're better off using intermediate variables rather than repeatedly performing the same operation. In this case, your problem is the `Me.lstAssigned.List(iCtr)` operation to retrieve the currently selected list item. By using an intermediate variable, I was able to get your code to work AND remove the item from that listbox without the second loop.

```
Private Sub btnMoveLeft_Click()
    Dim iCtr As Long
    Dim selectedValue As Variant
    For iCtr = 0 To Me.lstAssigned.ListCount - 1
        If Me.lstAssigned.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
            selectedValue = Me.lstAssigned.List(iCtr)
            Me.lstUnassigned.AddItem selectedValue
            lookValue = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(selectedValue, _
                                   Sheets("Pivot").Range("A:J"), 10, False)
            txtAC.Value = txtAC.Value - lookValue
            Me.lstAssigned.RemoveItem iCtr
        End If
    Next iCtr
End Sub

Private Sub btnMoveRight_Click()
    Dim iCtr As Long
    Dim selectedValue As Variant
    For iCtr = 0 To Me.lstUnassigned.ListCount - 1
        If Me.lstUnassigned.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
            selectedValue = Me.lstUnassigned.List(iCtr)
            Me.lstAssigned.AddItem selectedValue
            lookValue = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(selectedValue, _
                                   Sheets("Pivot").Range("A:J"), 10, False)
            txtAC.Value = txtAC.Value + lookValue
            Me.lstUnassigned.RemoveItem iCtr
        End If
    Next iCtr
End Sub
```